# HDD produces corrupted files, could it be the enclosure?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, file-corruption

I've purchased a new HDD and installed it in old enclosure to make it an external drive for my media center. 
After not being able to see any movie from this disk, because there were pixelations and strange colors during movie playback, and spending enough time in troubleshooting decoding options, I did a test playing back the movie on my laptop before copying it over to the external HDD. And it played back fine. While the same movie being copied to the external HDD and then back to the laptop did not.
So, I did a simple experiment with plain text files, and found out that files are getting corrupted in sizes over 100MB.
Here is an example showing the md5sum hash of a plain txt file when copied to the disk (Ovelix2) and then read back:

osmc@gimli:~$ cp 1GB /media/Ovelix2/

osmc@gimli:~$ cp /media/Ovelix2/1GB 1GB_FromOvelix

osmc@gimli:~$ md5sum 1GB*

c0744c4f34c41beda77c690f4d0ef018  1GB

7e9ed91cee56f406f5a3646c3b413e61  1GB_FromOvelix

osmc@gimli:~$ md5sum /media/Ovelix2/1GB

265523f1120f1a0ce0e82e5308312018  /media/Ovelix2/1GB

osmc@gimli:~$ md5sum /media/Ovelix2/1GB

8f0bbe29cfa531c165deb9efec91ca5a  /media/Ovelix2/1GB

osmc@gimli:~$

Everytime I read the file from the disk I get a different one.
I even saw the corruptions in the txt file, by using diff.
smartctl tool and badblocks did not reveal any problem on the disk.

Question is could the enclosure electronics (SATA to USB), e.g. some buffers, be the cause of the corruption? Or should I return the disk and get a replacement?

I don't have spare disk or enclosure, to test combinations.

Comment: Just seeing different hashes may not mean all that much (the difference may not be anything that actually affects the file).  However, if you compare the files with diff and see corruption, that's a different story.  Can you elaborate on the nature of the corruption you saw?  Also, are you saying that the behavior isn't consistent from time to time (you copy the same file twice and get different results each time)?

Comment: Corruptions were seen in the form of changed bits, i.e. different characters visible in the ascii text file. And yes, the md5 of each copy of the file from the external drive was producing a different hash. But the hash of the same copy produced always same hash. I didn't get the point in the first sentence above: "the difference may not... the file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could the enclosure electronics be the cause of the corruption?

With any electronic device, there's always a possibility of it malfunctioning.  So you can't rule that out.  I've run into strange issues, myself, where the enclosure USB interface caused problems, even when it was apparently working properly.

In my case, it didn't involve any form of file modification or corruption; mine have all been in the nature of compatibility issues between either the drive and the enclosure, or the enclosure vs. other enclosures connected concurrently.  Everything worked properly in most conditions, but failed in strange ways in certain situations.

One involved the drive working fine when used for storage, but causing unusual symptoms when using it as a system drive for certain Linux distros but not others.  Another involved plugging in one drive after having booted on another external drive (but no issue if the sequence was reversed).  These strange behaviors involved three or four different enclosures, and it was traced to the enclosure electronics; the drives, themselves, had no issues at all if inserted in a different enclosure.

My symptoms were totally different from yours, but it's evidence that the enclosure's interface can misbehave, even when appearing to be operational.

> Should I return the disk and get a replacement?

Your testing indicates that the drive doesn't appear to have a problem.  Before returning it, I would get another enclosure of a different brand, or test the drive with a USB adapter.  Either one is inexpensive, and will give you the tools to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I've purchased a new enclosure and the pair now works fine. Interestingly, the same files are now being read without errors from the drive, which means that it was the read operations that were problematic on the faulty enclosure, not the write ones, fortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. The power supply for the external chassis could generate interference adequate to disrupt file transfers, for one thing.